# Does the tune of hymn ‘With Harps and with Viols’ derive from Mendelssohn’s Symphony #5 scherzo?

Tags: classical-music, hymnody

The tune for hymn With ‘Harps and with Viols’ was written by Philip Bliss in 1874:

Mendelssohn wrote his Symphony #5, ‘Reformation’ in 1830,
including this scherzo as movement #2:

They sound rather similar to me, yet I’ve never seen this mentioned anywhere. Could it just be a coincidence, or could Bliss consciously or unconsciously have been influenced by the symphony?

Comment: The rhythms are similar, the melodies are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don’t think so. They simply share a short rhythmic motive which is 8. 16 | 4 4 in 3/4. But they differ vastly in terms of melody and structure.